# killBackgroundProcesses not working for multiple processes related to one package?

Tags: android, process

I'm try to restart several processes related to other app using killBackgroundProcesses().
I've added right uses-permission, and running system is above 2.2.
The app I want to restart have several processes defined in its menifest like:
`<receiver android:name=".remote.abcReceiver" android:process=":sub_process_a">`
`<receiver android:name=".remote.defReceiver" android:process=":sub_process_b">`

So there are three processes running in this app related to the same package like "com.example.restartme"

I 'm using the following code:

```
public static void killer() {
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)AppContext.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list= am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo apinfo = list.get(i);
        String tpName = apinfo.processName;
        if (tpName.contains("com.example.restartme"){

            String[] pkgList = apinfo.pkgList;
            Process.killProcess(apinfo.pid);
            // Process.killProcess(apinfo.pid);
            for (int j = 0; j < pkgList.length; j++) {
                am.killBackgroundProcesses(pkgList[j]);
                LogUtil.i("ActivityManager", "Killing process package:"
                        + pkgList[j]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the logcat I can see "Killing process package:com.example.restartme" was printed three times, but when I check the processes using ps, I can see only main process is killed and restarted but the two sub processes "com.example.restartme:sub_process_a" and "com.example.restartme:sub_process_b" stay the same without any change.

Any one met this problem before? Thanks in advance.